# Get list of videos from Tik Tok trending feed with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I'm trying to get a list of all of the video src links on the Tik Tok Trending page. However, `$$('video')` only returns one video. I found out that the page doesn't load a video until its clicked on, but even after doing so the selector only return one video. Additionally the query picture below doesn't doesn't list the video src attribute either.

What JQuery or Javascript selector can I use to return a list of videos.

[image]

Comment: The code in your screenshot isn't doing `$$("video")`. It's selecting a class name **only**. The second argument (`video`) is being ignored because [querySelectorAll only takes one argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). If you want to select video elements, try something like this for the selector: `video.jsx-whatever`

Comment: If you read my question carefully, you'll see that I stated the picture shows a different query. However, the goal of both queries is to return a list of videos. I can't return anything with `video.jsx-whatever` if react doesn't create that node until that part of the DOM is clicked on right?

Comment: That is correct. Additionally, I would expect the number in the class (`.jsx-123456468`) to change often, which will make it harder. Things like React make it way harder for third parties to work with websites. As for my comment, I was commenting mainly because I saw that there was a mistake in the screenshot.